# How to get count of each item in my SSRS report using an expression in the RDL file

Tags: sql, reporting-services, count, aggregate

I am a noob in SSRS reports. So please forgive any mistakes in the question. I have a SSRS report which looks like this

> `monday tuesday wednesday  thursday  friday  saturday  sunday`
>   `ABC`
>   `ABC`
>   `DEF`
>   `ABC`
>   `DEF`

I need to calculate count of each item in the list as follows

ABC 3
DEF 2

Is there a way to do this in the RDL using an expression such as aggregate or count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a tablix with (monday, tuesday, wednesday, ...) being your column groups and (ABC, ABC, DEF, ...) being your row groups all you need to do is `=COUNT(Fields!Foo.Value)` in each cell across. The local (grouped) scope will be applied.